# NSMutableDictionary "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: iphone, nsmutabledictionary

```
    -(void)saveDictionary:(int)counter
    {
        NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];
        NSString *test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counter];
        [theDictionary setObject:test forKey:@"Counter"]; <---- Error
        [theDictionary writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    }

    - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        [self saveDictionary:[_viewController counter]];
    }
```

Error:

```
-[NSCFString setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I can Load the value for Key "Counter" from plist. 
If I want to save the new value for same key "Counter" ... Error.
Need Help, spent hours.

bye

Here is the Code to initialize `theDictionary`:

```
-(void)initDictionary {
    if (theDictionary == nil) {
        NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];
        theDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        theString = [theDictionary objectForKey:@"Counter"];
    }
}
```

Found it!

```
theString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[theDictionary objectForKey:@"Counter"]];
```

Thanks All!

Answer (score 4):

This is because the object stored in `theDictionary` is actually an `NSString` and `NSString` doesn't contain a method called `-setObject:forKey`. Check your code for any places where `theDictionary` is being assigned and be sure that is actually an `NSMutableDictionary`.

Answer (score 3):

check the initilization .. you could have done it like this .

**NSMutableDictionary** *dictoForSyncing = [[**NSMutableArray** alloc] init];

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `theDictionary` is a string instead of an NSMutableDictionary. Where is it created and what happended to it in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

This says that 'theDictionary' is not a dictionary at all. Most likely it was released earlier and some NSString has taken its place.

Are you using ARC? Where was 'theDictionary' defined.

And have you tried the zombies Instrument to track this down? That should help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your property `theDictionary` isn't actually a dictionary, but a string (`NSString`). Where is `theDictionary` defined?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *myObjFromFile = ....;
NSMutableDictionary *tmpDictFromFile = 
  [[[myObjFromFile objectAtIndex:xx] mutableCopy]; mutableCopy];

[tmpDictFromFile setObject:"YOUR OBJECT"
                    forKey:"YOUR KEY"];
```